# Cannot open connection between Angular client and Spring Boot server via websockets

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I want to connect my Angular client to Spring Boot server via websockets(Sock.js and Stomp.js). But I receive this error in the browser:

[image: Error]

My websocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); // Enable a simple in-memory message broker
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app"); // Prefix for messages that are sent to controllers
    }
}
```

Websocket client on Angular:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Client, Message} from "@stomp/stompjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService {

  public client: Client;

  constructor() {
    this.client = new Client({
      brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8080/ws-endpoint', // Update this URL as needed
      debug: (msg: string) => {
        console.log(msg);
      }
    });
  }

  connect() {
    this.client.activate();
  }

  subscribe(destination: string, callback: (message: Message) => void) {
    this.client.subscribe(destination, callback);
  }

  sendMessage(destination: string, message: string) {
    this.client.publish({ destination, body: message });
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help. I will provide any info needed for solving this problem.

Comment: if you will replace `ws://localhost:8080/ws-endpoint` to `http://localhost:8080/ws-endpoint` i think it will work.

Comment: @AndreiLisa that doesn`t work. There is an error:
Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL's scheme must be either 'ws' or 'wss'. 'http' is not allowed.